# The method 'then' isn't defined for the type 'User' (firebase_auth: ^0.18.4+1)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I recently updated firebase auth to the latest version. Since then I have the following problem:

**The method 'then' isn't defined for the type 'User'.**

I am very grateful for any help!

This is my code:

```
  Future setUserData(Map<String, dynamic> userData) async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.then(
    (User user) async {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("Users")
          .doc(user.uid)
          .set(userData, SetOptions(merge: true),);
     },
     );
  }
```

Comment: you're awaiting and also using then. you could either wait or keep it async using then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the API documentation, [currentUser](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/currentUser.html) is just a property that contains a User object, or null.  It is not a promise, so you cannot call `then` on it, nor can you await it.  Just access it directly, and be sure to check for null before you use it.

```
  Future setUserData(Map<String, dynamic> userData) async {
    User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (user != null) {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("Users")
        .doc(user.uid)
        .set(userData, SetOptions(merge: true));
     }
     else {
       // decide what you want to do if there is no currentUser object.
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a possible solution below:

```
Future<void> setUserData(Map<String, dynamic> userData) async {
  User user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  if (user != null) {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("Users")
      .doc(user.uid)
      .set(userData, SetOptions(merge: true));
  } else {
      // user is not logged in
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can use either async and await keywords or then keyword!

I assume this should do just fine.

```
setUserData(Map<String, dynamic> userData) async {
   FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.then(
    (User user) async {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("Users")
          .doc(user.uid)
          .set(userData, SetOptions(merge: true),);
     },
     );
  }
```